# casting an enum through a void *

Tags: c, casting, pthreads, 32bit-64bit, porting

I'm trying to convert some old 32 bit code to 64 bit. One of the more frequent warnings I get is:

warning: cast of pointer to integer of different size

this happens when a function calls [pthread_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) which accepts a void * for passing data to the new thread. The calling thread puts in that void * an enum (hence the size mismatch in 64bit). Here's the code:

```
typedef enum {
zero,
one,
two
}numbers_e;

some_function(...)
{
    numbers_e mydata=zero;

    ...
    pthread_create(..., (void *)mydata);
    ...
}
```

I managed to overcome the warning with this:

```
pthread_create(..., (void *)0 + my_data);
```

this solution is very ugly (and I'm pondering if it's better to leave the warning as is with a big remark near the code using it). Is there another solution ?

Comment: The problem is that you are passing non-pointer data in as an argument to a function that is expecting a pointer.  You should be passing a pointer to the data as the function signature suggests and access it like it was a pointer appropriately within the function (if it's your code).

Comment: @jeff Mercado: I'ts not my code...

Comment: I know that the _pthread_create()_ function itself isn't your code, but the function that you pass in should be accessing the argument as a pointer.  Something you should be doing in general.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: I agree that this is bad usage in the first place. BUT: the new thread function isn't mine to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your solution is not only ugly, it is undefined behaviour (UB) that could cause you problems in the future:

- arithmetic on `void*` pointers is non standard and must be an
  extension of your compiler
- arithmetic on pointer that don't point to valid object is UB

To avoid the first you could use `(char*)0 + my_data`, but this would still leave you with the second.

What you could do

- cast your value to `uintptr_t`. this is a type that is guaranteed to
  be compatible with `void*`, if it exists. It exists on most modern
  platforms. The advatage would be that your code wouldn't compile on
  platforms where it doesn't exist, a clear indication that you'd have
  to change something, then.
- use a pointer to the data. this is the real solution, the way
  pthreads are designed

For both you'd have to modify the source of the called function, though, so you'd well change it to the second, the way how this should  be.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pass the address of the object.

```
pthread_create(..., (void *)&mydata);
```

That should be safe *edit* as long as `mydata` remains available somewhere.

Comment: thanks but that will not work in the cases where the enum is passed as a parameter to the function that's calling pthread_create

Comment: @Dror Cohen Can you post a code example of this ? I think it should work everywhere :-)

Comment: if the scope of the function calling pthread_create ends before the thread is actually running -> then I'm toast (see also @Omry answer)

Comment: @Dror Cohen **as long as mydata remains available somewhere**. If you don't like it, you're free keep incurring undefined behavior :-)

Comment: maybe it's not clear from the code sample but mydata isn't static. it's declared in the function that calls pthread_create

Comment: @Dror Cohen It's your job to make it stick somehow. Force the caller to send you a pointer, allocate memory and `memcpy` to it, etc. If you can't guarantee the caller will leave that memory alone until the thread is done, copying might be your own option. A far better option than sticking objects directly in a `(void *)`.

Answer (score 0):

passing a data as a pointer is hardly a good idea, but if there is a lot of code that does it - just leave it as is.
otherwise, I would pass the address as cnicutar suggested.
keep in mind that if mydata scope ends before the thread begins you may have a corruption problem.